# How to keep the formatting when copying from SSMS to Word

Tags: ms-word, ssms, copy-paste

I have a script in SSMS

I would like to copy it, complete with formatting and color-coding to Word

When I paste, it pastes as plain text

When I right-click in Word, I only get the option to paste as plain text (no option to paste and keep source formatting)

I've pasted from SSMS into Word before and never had an issue

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: What topics can I ask about here? Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: It depends on how much T-SQL text you copy. If it's done in smaller chunks (e.g. 100 lines), then it copies with the formatting. In my case, 145 lines worked, but 146 lines didn't (at least it still copied the text but without formatting), so it's probably a character or byte limit rather than a line limit. Another case of the proverbial Bill Gates being too clever for his own good and making decisions based on people and facts they know knowing about.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to make it paste correctly -

I copied half of the script, pasted, copied the second half, pasted

It might be an issue with the number of lines/size of the script?
The script is only 316 lines - so not sure